# Clicar em um marcador Google Map API e abrir um página

Tags: javascript, apache-cordova, jquery-mobile

Estou fazendo um site que irá conter vários marcadores, mas como fazer para que ao clicar no marcador, ao invés de abrir a janela padrão com informações do marcador, ele direcione para outra pagina ou abra uma janela modal?

Comment: Opinião pessoal: o que parece uma pergunta ampla demais ou que não pode ser reproduzida, aparentemente tem uma resposta extremamente específica. Luiz, se tiver oportunidade, por favor, acrescente um pouco do código que deu origem a sua pergunta. É bom pro SEO do site e talvez ajude outras pessoas com o mesmo problema. Valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que precisa fazer é ouvir o evento `click` de um `Marker`

```
marker.addListener('click', function() {
  // coloque aqui o que você quer fazer quando clicar no marker
})}
```